# Du könntest versuchen, sich zu registrieren

Tags: infinitive, reflexive

Kann man sagen: 'Du könntest zu registrieren versuchen' oder ist die Titelformulierung richtiger?

Was ist der Zweck von 'sich' hier? Solche Reflixivepronomen sind für mich etwas verwirrend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An diesem Beispiel wird die Relevanz von Reflexivpronomen mmN gut deutlich:

> a) Otto bemerkte, dass Karl **ihn** im Spiegel beobachtete.  (= Gegenstand
> der Beobachtung ist Otto) 
> b) Otto bemerkte, dass Karl **sich** im Spiegel
> beobachtete. (= Gegenstand der Beobachtung ist Karl) (Beispiel aus
> [Wikipedia: Reflexivpronomen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexivpronomen))

Es gibt also Verben, die einen Bezug zulassen (oder sogar fordern). So kann sich "waschen", "beobachten" oder auch "registrieren" auf jemand anderen oder auf sich selbst beziehen. Um diesen Unterscheid deutlich zu machen, wird das Reflexivpronomen eingesetzt.

> Ich registriere mich.
> Ich registriere ihn.
> Er versucht, sich zu registrieren.
> Du solltest versuchen, dich zu registrieren.

---

> Du könntest zu registrieren versuchen.

Dieser Satz ist aus verschiedenen Gründen ungrammatisch. Infinitvgruppen mit 'zu' würden am Ende stehen. "Richtiger" wäre etwas wie "Du könntest versuchen(,) *(dich)* zu registrieren."
Die Anordnung passiert nach dem Muster "Du könntest versuchen, [was könnte versucht werden?]."

> Du könntest versuchen, sich zu registrieren

In diesem Satz ist "sich" unpassen, da durch das "du" am Satzanfang impliziert wird, dass die angesprochene Person versuchen soll sich zu registrieren. In dieser direkten Ansprache muss es also heißen:

> Du könnntest versuchen, **dich** zu registrieren.